# Null has class?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

Symfony 1.4 and Propel are involved but I'm not sure they cause strange behaviour described below.

```
$this->_parent = TestPeer::retrieveByPK($this->getParentId());
var_dump(get_class($this->_parent), $this->_parent);
```

prints out 'Test' and 'null'.

How can it be this way?

PS

1/ $this->getParentId() returns integer and there is no corresponding record in DB, so $this->_parent should be null.

2/ php 5.5.6, xdebug, opcache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [The PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/get_class) for get_class:

> 5.3.0     NULL became the default value for object, so passing NULL to object now has the same result as not passing any value.

Which together with:

> Returns the name of the class of which object is an instance. Returns
> FALSE if object is not an object.
>
> If object is omitted when inside a class, the name of that class is
> returned.

...means that when passing null, you get the name of the class containing the call.